# Elasticsearch mapping with more than 1000 fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Index created with parent child and grandchild approach. Using Elasticsearch 6.2.4 version.

parent: 350, child: 150, grandchild: 600.

Is it good to exceed fields limit to 1500 from default limit 1000.

Answer (score 2):

We can change fields limit

```
PUT index_name/_settings
{
  "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 1500
}
```

**Just understand that more fields are more overhead.**

I think to exceed this limit is a sign that you are doing something that isn't going to work well with Elasticsearch in the future especially for performance.